# How to append a row to a dataframe with a bucle?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I've written a function to transform an excel sheet and take only one row from a monthly data. Mensually I'll have the data on a new excel sheet.
I've made this:

```
def bocapago(nombre):
  path='/content/drive/MyDrive/Fundacion Frontera Economica/Muni/python/inputs/BOCAS DE PAGO'
  filename = path + "/" + nombre.upper() + '.xlsx'

  input_cols=[0,1,2,3] # Columnas a importar
  df = pd.read_excel(filename,
                   header=0,
                   usecols = input_cols, 
                   index_col=False,
                   )
  
  df.columns = ['n_tasa','Fecha','Lugar','Importe']
  
  pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])
  df['Periodo'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Fecha']).month
  df['Periodo'] = nombre
  df['Periodo'] = df['Periodo'].str[:3] + "-" + df['Periodo'].str[-4:]
  
  df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Importe', index='Periodo', columns='Lugar', aggfunc='sum')
  df = df.assign(Total=df.sum(1))
  df = df.rename(columns={'Total':'TOTAL GENERAL'})
 
  df.head()
  return df
```

That is the function to read an proccess the sheet. And then I did this as a second step:

```
ENERO1 = bocapago('ENERO2021')
FEBRERO1 = bocapago('FEBRERO2021')
MARZO1 = bocapago('MARZO2021')
MAYO1 = bocapago('MAYO2021')

ingxboca = [ENERO1, FEBRERO1, MARZO1, MAYO1]

ingxboca = pd.concat(ingxboca)

ingxboca = ingxboca.merge(ingresos['TOTAL IACM'], how='left', on='Periodo')
ingxboca['DIFERENCIA'] = ingxboca['TOTAL IACM']-ingxboca['TOTAL GENERAL']

ingxboca.head()
```

I use another dataframe called "ingresos" on this case to merge.
My doubt is how can I do a for or while bucle to do the second step, so I can include all of it inside the function called "bocapago" or make another function like "finishing".

Answer (score 0):

I would keep bocapago as it's own function just like you've done and have the second function call it. It keeps the complexity of a single function lower and will be easier for code reuse in the future. IF I understood your question correctly, would this work?

```
def new_function(file_list:list):
    ingxboca = pd.concat([bocapago(f) for f in file_list])
    ingxboca = ingxboca.merge(ingresos['TOTAL IACM'], how='left', on='Periodo')
    ingxboca['DIFERENCIA'] = ingxboca['TOTAL IACM']-ingxboca['TOTAL GENERAL']

return ingxboca.head()
```

I'm not sure if that answered the question or not. If so, I imagine the list comprehension in the first line did it. keep in mind you can add if statements to a list comprehension. You can also pass in a string and use something like glob to give you a filelist with rules in it.

Comment: Thank you @m25. I've tried putting this:

    def tabla(file_list:list):
        ingxboca = pd.concat([bocapago(f) for f in file_list])
        ingxboca = ingxboca.merge(ingresos['TOTAL IACM'], how='left', on='Periodo')
        ingxboca['DIFERENCIA'] = ingxboca['TOTAL IACM']-ingxboca['TOTAL GENERAL']
        return ingxboca.head()

And then run this:

    file_list = [bocapago('ENERO2021'), bocapago('FEBRERO2021'), bocapago('MARZO2021')]
    tabla(file_list)

But I have an upper error. I think that what you proposed is right but I don't know how to run it.

Comment: filelist = ['ENERO2021','FEBRERO2021', ... ] . In other words, file_list should be a list of strings, not dataframes.

pd.concat([bocapago(f) for f in file_list]) is  list comprehension that acts as a for-loop. it runs bocapago on each item in file_list. The result is a list of dataframes. The method you stated above would run bocapago 2 times.